# Security of web services (REST & SOAP)

Tags: web-service, rest

I'm doing a state of the art on web services security. I need every bit of a solution out there that solves concerns about identification, access control, transmission related ones like data integrity, protection, non repudiation..

So I fetched some real world solution to fill those needs, I found those for SOAP based web services:

Identification: WS-Security Framework

Authentication: Extensible Access Control Markup Language (XACML)

Authorization

- Extensible Rights Markup Language (XrML)
- XML Key Management (XKMS)
- Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML)
- .NET Passport
- Confidentialité
- WS-Security Framework
- XML-Encryption
- Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
- WSS

And almost all of them are implementable using spring-security

On the other hand RESTful web services having the reputation to be less secure. Being based on the web SSL/TLS is a great solution for encryption, but other security protocols do exist like:

- OAuth: used by facebook, twitter, without tokens exchange
- OpenID: used by google
- CAS
- LDAP
- Kerberos
- Persona
- BrowerID

Another solution may be to integrate the security in the enterprise bus as a service (Security as a Service)..

So my question is : Are there any other solutions I should know about?

Comment: Just a quick correction - .Net Passport doesn't exist any more.  It was supplanted by Live ID (Now Microsoft Accounts) for Microsoft sites, and Live Connect which is an OAuth 2.0 provider for non-Microsoft sites.

Comment: Hi @Ozama - welcome to Security Stack Exchange. If you take a look at the [faq] you will see that questions like this, which ask for opinions are not really suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

The list provided is just covering authentication and authorization of web services,  which is one, very small component of security.  Most of the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) applies to web services.